# preventDefault() overruled by window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, href, preventdefault

I have process in my website which contains a few steps. To navigate I have "previous" and "next" buttons. These buttons are `<a>` elements with an href attribute (to visit the previous and next step).

The next button works as a door to the next step, but also to validate some fields in the current step, before it continues.

So this is what happens when clicking the next button:

1. The href value got saved in a variable `$url`.
2. `preventDefault()` prevents the link from opening the URL.
3. There are some validation checks done.
4. If they return "true", the `$url` will be loaded in window.location.

For some steps I need to do another check to the user with a confirm box. But here comes the problem:

**Problem:**

When the `confirm()` returns "false", the user should not go to the next page. But the `window.location` of function 1 "overrules" the `preventDefault()` of function 2 now.

**1. Default next button function:**

```
$('#next_link').click(function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();             
    if(wiz_validate_required() && wiz_is_step_done()) {
        window.location = url;  
    } 
});
```

**2. Confirm box function:**

```
$('.dimensions-check').click(function(e) {
    if(confirm('Have you specified the dimensions in millimeters?') == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is dimensions-check? Does this and next_link co-exist somewhere?

Maybe you should create a function that uses a confirm box and return true or false and then procceed with the click event but you need to share more code to get a straight answer!

Comment: can you put an if statement in step 1 to not set `$url` if the second check is required? ie. `if(!secondCheckRequired){//set $url}`

Comment: @idioteque dimensions-check and next_link co-exists indeed and are and ID and class on the same button. That's the problem. I need to hold these two functions seperate, otherwise there was no problem, and I putted everyting in one function. And there is no more code to share, because only these two functions conflict with each other. BTW the  wiz_validate_required() and wiz_is_step_done() functions don't give the problem, I have checked that.

Comment: In my opinion you don't have to re-direct again from JS. Just don't call event.preventDefault() and that should be stopped. Just check this http://jsfiddle.net/4e8qa65o/3/

Comment: I think you may have another event assigned to that anchor, so your `preventDefault does not work`. If you have `$('a.mya').on('click'....` and `$('a').on('click'....` both events will be triggered. If this is the case, you have to unregister your events.

Comment: @VinodKumar No I need it because I need to do some checks before the re-direct.

Comment: @Robbert sure you may check. Just prevent when you don't want to allow rather than preventing all the time and redirecting once again. See the jsfiddle link from my previous comment, you will understand.

Comment: @VinodKumar But it is not the preventing that is the problem, it is the redirecting (window.location)

Comment: @Robbert just use direct dom method .onclick = function(){} That should do. In my jsfiddle link it works!! If it does not work for you, please let me know your browser details.

Comment: @VinodKumar We don't understand each other the right way. Look at my "Default next button function" (see question). I need the preventDefault and window.location = $url, because otherwise the validation functions don't run before the redirect. It has nothing to do with whether the preventdefault() function is working right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like that. If you have any question for the code please ask!

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codegaze/u47s4nh3/1/)

```js
    // These can be changed for each step if you want or not a confirmation 
   var needs_confirm = true;
   var cb_message = 'Have you specified the dimensions in millimeters?';

   $('#next_link').click(function(e) {

     var url = $(this).attr('href');
     e.preventDefault();

     if (needs_confirm === true) {
       if (confirm_box(cb_message) === true) {
         redirect_window(url);
       }
     } else {
       redirect_window(url);
     }

   });


   function confirm_box(cb_message) {
     if (confirm(cb_message) === true) {
       return true;
     } else {
       return false;
     }
   }

   function redirect_window(url) {
     if (wiz_validate_required() && wiz_is_step_done()) {
       window.location = url;
     }
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="next_link"><a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you called the dimension-check?

e.preventDefault() only cancel the default action of a button which is submit the form. Regardless of e.preventDefault windows.location will always redirect you.

```js
$('#next_link').click(function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();             
    if(wiz_validate_required() && wiz_is_step_done()) {
        //If dimension isnot prompt{
          //windows.location
        //}else call dimension prompt
            
    } 
});
```

You can put the windows.location like this:

```js
$('.dimensions-check').click(function(e) {
    if(confirm('Have you specified the dimensions in millimeters?') == true) {
        window.location = url;
    }
});
```